# How do I plot box plot for multiple columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe (pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame). I would like to plot the numeric columns in a boxplot to detect outliers.

I started by selecting only the numeric columns with:

```
numeric_columns = [item[0] for item in df.dtypes if item[1].startswith('float')]
```

I tried to use plotly, but then I saw that first I needed to convert to a pandas Dataframe.
So, I did:

```
df_pd = df.toPandas()

fig = px.box(df_pd[numeric_columns])
fig.show()
```

I got an error:
"Command result size exceeds limit: Exceeded 20971520 bytes (current = 20973190)"

I guess the dataset is too big to work with pandas. Could you help me? Is it possible to create the plots directly in a pyspark dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be cautious of `toPandas`. Spark is used for "big data" analysis, e.g. when data doesn't feet in one computer. When you run `toPandas`, your data is collected from you cluster to the server where you run your Python process.

Secondly, in order to fix your error, you need to properly configure the Spark session. You need to set `driver.memory` and `maxResultSize` parameters to be larger than your dataset

It may look like

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

app_name = 'Your App'

conf = {
    
    # some basic stuff

    'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled': 'true',
    'spark.shuffle.service.enabled': 'true',
    'spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors': 10,
    'spark.executor.memory': '32g',
    'spark.executor.cores': '4',

    # driver params
    'spark.driver.memory': '2g',
    'spark.driver.maxResultsSize': '2g',

    # some other params here
}

builder = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName(app_name)
)

for k, v in conf.items():
    builder.config(k, v)

spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

Thirdly, if your dataset is larger than your local process capacities, use sampling

```py
# sample 1% of data
pdf = df.sample(0.01).toPandas()
```